# Get Ip address function not working well

Tags: c, sockets, ip

I'm trying to get the ip address of my server, but it gets 127.0.1.1 instead of 127.0.0.1.  Where is the error? Also how can I get the real IP address, not the localhost address.

```
#define MAXHOSTNAME 256
#define DEBUG


    char * getIPAddress()
    {
        char myname[ MAXHOSTNAME + 1 ];
        static char IPinASCII[ MAXHOSTNAME ];   /* Oversized */
        struct hostent * hp;

        memset( myname, 0, MAXHOSTNAME + 1 );   /* Init */
        memset( IPinASCII, 0, MAXHOSTNAME );

        gethostname( myname, MAXHOSTNAME );
    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf( "hostname is %s\n", myname );
    #endif /* DEBUG */

        hp = gethostbyname( myname );
        if( hp == NULL )
        {
            perror( "gethostbyname" );
            return( "IP not found" );
        }

        inet_ntop( hp->h_addrtype, hp->h_addr_list[ 0 ], IPinASCII,
            MAXHOSTNAME ) ;

    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf( "canonical hostname is %s at IP %s\n", hp->h_name, IPinASCII );
    #endif /* DEBUG */

        return( IPinASCII );
    }
```

user@user-desktop:~/Desktop/My Code$ ./ipprint 
hostname is user-desktop
canonical hostname is user-desktop at IP 127.0.1.1
127.0.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what your `/etc/hosts` indicates. It most likely has something like:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       user-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in `/etc/hosts`. It's a default entry, and `gethostbyname()` also looks there.